# Intellij show error for object X is not a member of package

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

When I build my sbt project in Intellij I get the following error:

```
Error:(7, 8) object DfUtils is not a member of package com.naturalint.xspark.common.sparkutils
```

import com.naturalint.xspark.common.sparkutils.DfUtils

The object is a part of the package and when I ran sbt compile or package or assembly in terminal everything clears fine. When I move the object to a different location in the project it sometimes work for a day and then again gives the error

This is the content of the file:

```
package com.naturalint.xspark.common.sparkutils

import org.apache.spark.sql._

import scala.reflect._


object DfUtils {

def removeColumnThatAreNotInEncoder[T <: Product : ClassTag: Encoder](dataEntity: Dataset[T]): Dataset[T] = {

  val declaredFields: Array[String] = classTag[T].runtimeClass.getDeclaredFields.map(x => x.getName)

  val columns: Array[Column] = declaredFields.map(x => new Column(x))

  dataEntity.select(columns: _*).as[T]
 }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Nir

Comment: Have you done invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: yes. it didn't help

Comment: Do you also get this error when building in sbt from the command line?

Comment: no, it works fine from command line

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Could you please open an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL and if possible attach an example project that shows the error